# get X instances of type Y in constructor

Tags: c#, autofac

If I set my dependencies up with AutoFac in the following code how can I make sure that `objects.ToList()` returns a list with X number of elements?

```
public interface IClassA { ... }
public class ClassA : IClassA { ... }

public interface IClassB { ... }
public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    public ClassB(IEnumerable<IClassA> objects)
    {
    }
}
```

Current container building code (note that this is used in conjunction with TopShelf):

```
public static class DependencyContainer
{
    public static IContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IClassA>();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IClassB>().SingleInstance();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? With this registration you should get an array of IClassA with one element in your ClassB constructor...

Comment: @nemesv yes but I want an array with 4 elements. or 10. or X. I need to be able to configure how many. and of course it needs to be different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the following to your `DependencyContainer` class then you can indicate what instances should be injected into the `ClassB` constructor:

```
    builder.Register(c => 
                return new [] { c.Resolve<IClassA>(), c.Resolve<IClassA>() })
           .As<IEnumerable<IClassA>>();
```

So:

```
public static class DependencyContainer
{
    public static IContainer BuildContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IClassA>();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IClassB>().SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => 
            return new [] { c.Resolve<IClassA>(), c.Resolve<IClassA>() })
               .As<IEnumerable<IClassA>>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

If you wanted to dynamically create a number at runtime you could add the following to the `DependencyContainer` class:

```
public static IEnumerable<IClassA> CreateInstances(IComponentContext component)
{
    const int number = 3; // <-- YOU COULD READ THIS FROM A CONFIG FILE
    List<IClassA> instances = new List<IClassA>();

    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        instances.Add(component.Resolve<IClassA>());
    }

    return instances;
}
```

And then replace the `Register(c => return new [] { ... })` with:

```
builder.Register(c => CreateInstances(c)).As<IEnumerable<IClassA>>();
```